# Python / PHP time difference

Tags: php, python-2.7, datetime

I having a time issue from python to php.

when I use the code below my python time is different to the php time.

does this mean its getting the time from the server and not the script pc?

If so how can I make it read and use the time from the python script?

```
import datetime 
import requests 
import re

d = datetime.datetime.now()
format = "%d/%m/%y %H:%M"
now = d.strftime(format)
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'} 
print now
message = 'the time is now:' + now 
payload = {'text': message,
              }
send = requests.post('http://192.168.1.14/test.php', data=payload, headers=headers) 
result = re.sub('<[^>]*>', '',send.text) 
print result
```

result

```
25/09/17 18:58
the time is now: 25/09/17 06:25
```

as you can see there is a huge time difference.

php

```
<?php 
echo $_POST['text']
?>
```

this is all done for a test server that I can't change the time on. The python pc has correct time

Comment: You must have an idea which time is closer to that of the server clock, why don't you mention that? Where are you running Python and PHP, on your PC or on the server?

Comment: could it be you use %m in PHP for the minutes? As it should be %i

Comment: and also the actual server time so we know which one is wrong

Comment: the python pc has correct time. php has random set. as this is an example setup for a server i have no access to change the time

Comment: @KIKOSoftware python is on a separate pc to server. python time is correct

Comment: As the PHP file simply echoes the text that is sent to it from the python file, and doesn't even read the time itself, then the problem is in the python script

Comment: Now that we can see your PHP I can honestly say that the problem you report seems to be impossible. Both times should always be the same. Not even bad caching could cause this, I hope.

Comment: so i just tested another pc to the "real" site and it worked so ill close this and look at why one works and other doesn't